# Java String.split(), how to prevent empty element in the new array

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String like

```
String s="hello.are..you";
String test[]=s.split("\\.");
```

The test[] includes 4 elements:

```
hello
are

you
```

How to just generate three not empty elements using split()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a quantifier

```
String[] array = "hello.are..you".split("\\.+");
```

To handle a leading `.` character you could do:

```
String[] array = ".hello.are..you".replaceAll("^\\.",  "").split("\\.+");
```

Comment: sorry, but what if the String is ".hello"

Comment: are you expecting the same output?